# Is there any Limit on the TPS in JPOS

Tags: jpos

I am using Jmeter to post ISO XML Message to 8000 port and same is read using XMLChannel.
Once it receives i append a few fields and puts the message into context

But the problem is i cannot go more than 100 TPS on my windows xp Machine. Are there any other settings do be done to increase TPS

Answer (score 1):

jPOS per se is very fast, a simple auto-responder can get you over 4000 TPS sustained load (I get 4400 on my regular MBP). But once you add your business logic and database access, your mileage may vary. Take a look at http://jpos.org/tutorials and try the Gateway example, that one is quite fast.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I have used Jmeter to Simulate the load and not getting the expected TPS. Just wanted to know the tool used by you to get 4000 TPS?

Comment: The tool used are client and server simulators provided with jposee. If you follow the tutorial mentioned it will help you to get the prerequisites.